# Change data capture in Redis

Tags: redis, change-data-capture

I am trying to implement a change data capture of redis keys, where I want to be notified when a key is modified (updated, created, deleted, etc).

The only option I was able to find out is `Redis Keyspace Notification`.
I am able to enable that and implement the notification, but in the notification part I only see the information of the key which is modified along with the command that modified it, but I don't get any information about the value part.

Is there a way to get the value information of the key?

Example:
Let's say there is a hash-map with name of ankit.
When I run this command:

```
hset ankit role developer
```

I only see information in the keyspace channel as:

```
__keyspace@0__:ankit
hset
```

I don't get any information about the value part like which sub-key was added and with what value `(role:developer)`. Is there a way to get that?